# How do I bypass kafka broker failure when starting springboot server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-applications, apache-kafka

I am facing an issue in my spring-boot(2.1.7.RELEASE) app server which uses spring-boot-Kafka('spring-Kafka' -'2.2.7.RELEASE') integration library to access my Kafka topics.

When my Kafka brokers are down, my application is unable to start.

This is what I get:

```
2019-10-06 02:41:02.764  WARN -- [main           ] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient                       [] : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=caas] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-06 02:41:31.777 ERROR -- [main           ] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication                   [] : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:893)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1203)
    at com.zinka.fmsclients.FmsClientsApplication.main(FmsClientsApplication.java:14)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
```

Is there a way to bypass this dependency on Kafka brokers? I want my application to start even if brokers are unavailable/down. App Server should be able to connect once the brokers are up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a container property `missingTopicsFatal`:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ContainerProperties.html#isMissingTopicsFatal--
that allows an application to start even if the topic and/or broker is not available.

```
@Bean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
    ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactor,
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {

  ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory =
      new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
  configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactor);

  ContainerProperties containerProperties = factory.getContainerProperties();
  containerProperties.setMissingTopicsFatal(false);

  ...
  return factory;
}
```

Comment: Topic not available and broker not available are 2 different things!! Is there any way to bypass checking the kafka server state while starting the spring boot application?

Comment: The application also starts when the broker is not available, works at least on my kubernetes cluster. Did you test the setting?

Comment: Yeah I tested it, using embedded and external tomcat servers. And it didn't work. We are not using Kubernetes as of now!! anyways thanks

Comment: Hi, I retested and validated that this still works with Spring Boot 2.3. The application starts and begins to search for a kafka broker, if the broker becomes available it starts to consume messages, if the broker disappears the application continues to search for the broker. Here is a working sample application: https://github.com/AndreasKl/stackoverflow-58252409

Comment: Thank you!! I tested now with spring boot 2.1.6, it works. I tested that initially when I started playing with the properties, it could have failed for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is the change in newer version of spring.

```
@Component
class ContainerFactoryConfigurer {

    ContainerFactoryConfigurer(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> factory) {
        factory.getContainerProperties().setMissingTopicsFatal(false);
    }

}
```